# XmlException: Character '=' may not be contained within a name

Tags: xml, sapi, ssml

SAPI5 in combination with the flag SVSFIsXML allows inserting custom tags, for example in such a form:

```
 <customtag>Speak this text</customtag>
```

This tag would be recognized as

```
FragList->State.eAction == SPVA_ParseUnknownTag
```

However, when I use the new standard SSML, the following XML code raises the error

```
Invalid XML content:
Inner Exception: XmlException: The character '=' (hex value 0x3D) may not be contained within a name. Line 1, position 126.
```

This is the code:

```
<speak version='1.0' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang='en-US'>
<voice name='Microsoft Sam'>
<customtag="1">
 Speak this text!
</customtag>
</voice>
</speak>
```

And the following XML code raises a different error:

```
System.FormatException: The element "customtag" is invalid.
```

This is the code:

```
<speak version='1.0' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang='en-US'>
<voice name='Microsoft Sam'>
<customtag>
 Speak this text!
</customtag>
</voice>
</speak>
```

If I remove the customtag, it works fine.

Is there any obvious XML error in my code, or does using custom tags simply not work anymore?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any obvious XML error in my code

`<customtag="1">` is an obvious error. Element names are not attributes and can't have values.

> or does using custom tags simply not work anymore?

The whole point of XML is to allow custom markup languages to be designed.

You appear to have a Speech Synthesis document, which uses a custom markup language designed using XML.

The 'The element "customtag" is invalid ' error message says that `customtag` is not allowed in a Speech Synthesis document.

It is possible to design a Speech Synthesis + Something Else markup language, but your tool isn't testing for that. It is requiring a pure Speech Synthesis document.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `<customtag="1">` is not well-formed XML. I don't know the tools you are using, but it seems they have allowed you to create ill-formed XML, which obviously won't parse.